# List the contents of multiple .tar archive files

Tags: linux, shell, archive, tar

To list the content of one `.tar` archive file I use

```
tar -tvf archive.tar
```

and I was hoping to use similar format to list the contents from more files, but

```
tar -tvf *.tar
```

is not working as I expected.

What is the best **one line solution** to list the contents of multiple `.tar` archive files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

does this help?

```
for f in *.tar 
do 
    echo "content of $f:"
    tar tvf "$f"
done
```

Comment: @Ωmega this is the best answer you're going to get. Add some semicolons and it'll fit on one line. `tar` doesn't do multiple archives in a single run. I can't think of any archiver that can do the equivalent without a shell loop - `ar`, `unzip`, `unrar`, `cpio`, `pax`... all of them just do one archive per invocation, like `tar`. It isn't a bug and the shell loop isn't a workaround. Shells have loop commands because loops are useful sometimes. This is one of those times.

Answer (score 2):

*one liner* as requested

```
find . -type f -name "*.tar" | xargs -n 1 -i bash -c "echo {}; tar tvf {}; echo" | less
```